# ChromeWebdriver - Issue getting href inside a div

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping some data on Instagram for a research and I am having the following issue. When I select the class that contains the pictures:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_mck9w")
```

I got a list of Webdriver elements but then I want to access the href of the image (get a list of the links of the pictures) but it returns a list of  none:

```
all_links = [u.get_attribute("href") for u in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_mck9w")]
```

The html structure from where I do it as is as follows:

[html snippet structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONokB.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What really contains `href` attribute is `a` but not `div`. `[u.find_element_by_name("a").get_attribute("href") for u in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_mck9w")]`

Comment: Thank you, it works great ;)